# APA citation style - capitalization of titles

Tags: tools, citations, apa

I'm writing a paper, supposedly using APA citation style, and I've encountered the following conflict. 
On the one hand, the title of the work I cite is cited in all small letters, and only the first word (and a word directly following a colon) are capitalized, for example:

> Liard, J. (1990). *Deductive reasoning.* Annual Review of Psychology.

or

> Anderson, J. N. (2000). Secular responses to the problem of induction.

But what if the title of one work contains not only a noun, but a name, such as:

> Salmon, W. (1974). An encounter with david hume.

(David Hume was a British philosopher.)
Do I, or do I not, capitalize the words "David Hume"? and if so, does anyone maybe even know how to force this in JabRef/LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should capitalize the name as you should other proper nouns. See this article and the links within: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/how-to-capitalize-author-names-in-apa-style.html

You can preserve the capitals for the proper nouns by using braces:

```
title={An encounter with {D}avid {H}ume}
```

I believe with JabRef you can go to preferences and put 'title' in the section where you 'Store the following fields with braces around caps' (maybe not the exact name of the field, but it should be obvious).